# What does this Rails Engine code mean: config.to_prepare &method(:activate).to_proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm working with Spree, which uses Rails engines extensively. A common pattern I find is this. However I have trouble understanding this code.

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine 
  def self.activate
    ...
  end     

  config.to_prepare &method(:activate).to_proc
end
```

1. What does `.to_prepare` do
2. What does the `&method` operator do?
3. What is the overall effect of the code?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**`&method(:activate).to_proc`**

This is best consumed one item at a time. (It should be noted that this portion of the code is 100% *non*-Rails-specific Ruby.)

`method` is a Ruby method (it's all very meta). It [is documented thusly](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038):

> Looks up the named method as a
>   receiver in obj, returning a Method
>   object (or raising NameError). The
>   Method object acts as a closure in
>   obj’s object instance, so instance
>   variables and the value of self remain
>   available.

Check out the following IRB session:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > def my_method
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002?>   puts "in my_method"
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003?>   10
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > method(:my_method)
 => #<Method: Object#my_method>
```

So the `method` call is looking up (in your example) the `activate` method and creating a [`Method` object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Method.html) for it. `Method` contains a method called `to_proc`, which "[returns a Proc object corresponding to this method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Method.html#M001069)". Continuing our IRB session:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006 > method(:my_method).to_proc
 => #<Proc:0x000001010a3e38 (lambda)>
```

Finally, we use the ampersand operator, which, when preceding a `Proc` object during a method call, will be replaced by the block the `Proc` contains. One more time in IRB:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > def executor(&block)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008?>   block.call
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :010 > executor( &method(:my_method).to_proc )
in my_method
 => 10
```

So, in pseudocode, what the line you listed is saying is:

```
config.to_prepare(a block containing the functionality of the method activate)
```

**`config.to_prepare`**

[Edited based on schof's comment]

`config.to_prepare` takes a block that should be run to set up your Railtie/Engine. It is run once in production mode and on every request in development, and is the *only* code guaranteed to be called on every single request in development mode. This is important if you are modifying classes (`class_eval`, etc.) as part of your engine initialization; otherwise, you're going to see different behavior in development vs. production.

**But Why?**

The reason this is a common idiom is so that you don't have to define your preparation code inside the `to_prepare` block itself; you can define method(s) in your class and then convert them to a block (which remembers its scope) using the magic described above. The code is functionally equivalent to:

```
class Engine < Rails::Engine 
  config.to_prepare do
    (the contents of self.activate)
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Just wanted to add that the config.to_prepare stuff is the only thing guaranteed to be called on every single request in development mode.  This is important if you are modifying classes (class_eval, etc.) as part of your engine init.  Otherwise you're going to see different behavior in development vs. production.